# multi element directive on different DOM nodes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

For example, I have next html:

```
<header myDirective>  <!-- 1 -->
    ...
</header>
<div menu>
    ...
</div>
... <!-- here are some html -->
<section>
    <div myDirective>  <!-- 2 -->
        ...
    </div>
</section>
```

I want that myDirective with comment  and myDirective with comment  which are set on different DOM nodes, were combined. I mean I want that inside
directive link function I would get param "element" which would contain both of these DOM nodes. I know about property multiElement, but it works only on siblings if I understood
correctly this property. How can I get what I want? For example, I can have even such html(numbers in comments show which DOM nodes must be combined):

```
<header myDirective>  <!-- 1 -->
    <div myDirective>  <!-- 2 -->
        ...
    </div>
    <div myDirective>  <!-- 2 -->
        ...
    </div>
</header>

<div myDirective>  <!-- 3 -->
    ...
</div>
<div myDirective>  <!-- 3 -->
    ...
</div>
<div myDirective>  <!-- 1 -->
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smth like this is done by introducing some top-level parent directive in combine with several child directives. Child directives require parent one so they can use parent controller.
html:

```
<div main>
  <div mydir><div><div mydir>1
  </div></div></div>
  <span mydir>2
  </span>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('mydir', function() {
  return {
    require : '^main',
    link : function(scope, el, attrs, mainCtrl) {
      mainCtrl.register(el);
    }
  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/znFa6lGUGmQ0bYw097zH?p=preview